# Ayuda con la implemetación de un método

Tags: java, sqlite

Implementé un método que me devuelve una lista de paradas de ómnibus,pero lo que necesito devolver es un cursor.El segundo cursor del método me va a devolver una lista con las guaguas que paran en una parada de ómnibus determinada .Aqui les dejo el método para ver si me pueden ayudar a entender.

```
public ArrayList<Parada> getParadas() {
        ArrayList<Parada> results = new ArrayList<Parada>();
        Cursor cursor = dataBase.rawQuery("select nombre, direccion, lat, lon, id from puntos where id in (select distinct punto from paradas)", null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Parada p = new Parada(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getFloat(2), cursor.getFloat(3));
                ArrayList<String> rutas = new ArrayList<>();
                Cursor cursor2 = dataBase.rawQuery("select distinct a.nombre from rutas a, recorridos b, paradas c, puntos d where b.ruta=a.id and c.tipo_recorrido=1 and c.recorrido=b.id and c.punto=" + cursor.getInt(4), null);
                if (cursor2.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        rutas.add(cursor2.getString(0));
                    } while (cursor2.moveToNext());
                }
                cursor2.close();
                p.setRutas(rutas);
                results.add(p);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return results;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Por qué necesitas devolver el cursor? Es mejor devolver los datos necesarios. Si necesias aplicar filtros a tus datos en base a datos de otra tabla, mejor utiliza un `JOIN` entre tus tablas y filtras todo el bloque de datos.

Comment: Pienso que devolviendo el cursor es mas rapido en la busqueda de la parada mas cercana a la posicion del usuario

Comment: No lo es. Esto suele llevar a muchos problemas, hasta podría ser considera un anti patrón de diseño. Lo mejor es utilizar un JOIN en lugar de utilizar dos sentencias como lo vienes haciendo.